# Photo management utilities

Tags: web-hosting, cms, photo-gallery, photo

I'm about to develop a web site for a new client. It's not going to be very intense, but one requirement is that, if possible, the client wants to be able to manage the photo gallery themselves.

Since they are not technically savvy at all, I was wondering what utilities exist that provide a GUI for users to log in to manage photos. Can anyone make a recommendation?
I haven't purchased the web hosting yet, so if your answer requires a specific type of host server don't worry, I am open to options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com) a try. It provides a file browser which supports basic copy & paste, file uploading, thumbnails, picture resizing and HTML form integrations. And you can modify it to suit your own needs since it's open-source. I think it is perfect for photo managing.

Demo avaliable [here](http://ckfinder.com/demo).

Um... I found a good alternative to CKFinder, it's called [AjaXplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/). It provides a neat interface, plus user management system, and a simple tool allowing users to get a public url of a file. It also allows users to set file permissions and metadata. Demo [here](http://ajaxplorer.info/demo)(username/pw="demo").

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of thing I'm looking for. I'll leave the question open in case other people have opinions on other products.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know which gallery you will be using on the frontend. For example if it was [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) or similar or something different.

With that said, I will add some options for you to checkout as well.

I find clients really enjoy [SlideShowPro Director.](http://slideshowpro.net/products/slideshowpro_director/) It's a commercial product though, is well worth the price.

[GalleryCMS](http://www.gallerycms.com/) is a free CMS for images and galleries.

I've never actually tried this so, I'm not postive it will be a good fit or not though, you can [check out ZenPhoto](http://www.zenphoto.org) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If they have a lot of photos using a hosted service like www.smugmug.com could be a nice option. They also allow you to embed galleries on your website, but all the uploading and arranging is done on their website.

Comment: Jeremiah brings up a good point as well. Sometimes clients already have accounts for images for example Flickr might be another one to think about. Those can be tied into their website galleries in different ways.

Comment: Picasa Web Albums might be another option as well now that I think about it.